# Query Presto through HUE-AWS EMR: 'CLASSPATH' eror

Tags: emr, hue, presto

I'm using AWS EMR and I'm trying to use hue notebook to query presto on Hue 3.12.

I get a 'CLASSPATH' error.

Went over https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-5859 but saw that dbproxy_extra_classpath property is located correctly in [notebook] sections root (above [notebook].[[interpreters]]).

I have also declared 'ClassPATH' parameter and restarted HUE but still get the same error.

Any advise?

Thanks.